# Problema com strlen()

Tags: c, string, entrada-de-dados

Por que esse código está imprimindo um número a mais sendo que eu inicializei a variável como `0`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void ) {

    char texto[50]; int cont = 0;

    printf("\nInforme seu nome completo: ");
    fgets(texto,50,stdin);

    cont = strlen(texto);

    printf("\nO tamanho da string: %i\n",cont);

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Que número a mais está imprimindo? O tamanho do texto?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

O [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) inclui o caractere de fim de linha digitado na entrada de dados na *string*, por isso mostra um caractere a mais.

Vamos fazer o código imprimir os códigos ASCII de cada caractere para ver o que está dentro da *string*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char texto[50];
    printf("\nInforme seu nome completo: ");
    fgets(texto, 50, stdin);
    int cont = strlen(texto);
    printf("\nO tamanho da string: %i\n", cont);
    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++) printf("%d ", texto[i]);
    texto[cont - 1] = '\0';
    cont = strlen(texto);
    printf("\nO tamanho da string: %i\n", cont);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2bHheU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gfowsnud-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/StringTerminator.c).

A solução é colocar o caractere nulo que é o terminador da *string* no lugar do caractere de nova linha. Não fiz de forma portável, no Windows o fim de linha são dois caracteres.

Este código feito para ilustrar melhor a mudança, isso está correto, mas não é assim que sew costuma fazer código real no resto dele.