# Imprimir as letras à frente do alfabeto

Tags: c, string, ascii

A ideia do código era entrar com uma letra, por exemplo 'a' e retornar uma letra a frente no alfabeto, no caso a letra 'b', porém o programa não retorna nada e eu não consigo achar o problema

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str[100];

    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    for (int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
        printf("%c", str[i]+1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: teoricamente está fazendo isso acabei de testar (tem modificações a fazer no código), mas, ele está funcionando sim. (mudanças não precisa do for, por exemplo)

Comment: Um ponto que você tem que considerar é que como você fala de "letra" então tem que decidir será será circular ou não, isto é, se a letra seguinte a 'z' deve ou não ser 'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que verificar se encontrou a quebra de linha, porque é isso que o `fgets()` coloca quando você encerra a digitação. Também pode verificar se encontrou o terminador nulo da *string*.

A eficiência do código era péssima, tinha complexidade quadrática, fiz ficar linear, [tirando o `strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101). E corrigi o erro que estouraria o *buffer*.

Se o código fosse usado para outras coisas teria que mudar q quebra de linha para o terminador. Pode ser visto em [Problema com strlen()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157168/101) e [Texto parece cheio de lixo depois de digitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320255/101).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[101];
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; str[i] && str[i] != '\n'; i++) printf("%c", str[i] + 1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HmGBdI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qdycsbuc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Fgets.c).